# OAuth2 Login Spring Security use HTTP Post for Authorization Endpoint Request

Tags: spring, post, spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I've been creating an OAuth2 Login application with Spring Security and have been making good progress, The Identity Provider I am working with requires that their /authorization endpoint be triggered with an HTTP POST.

I've been doing some testing and it seems that Spring Security triggers the /authorization endpoint by a GET request.

From looking at the OAuth RFC documentation, I see the following.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1

> The authorization server MUST support the use of the HTTP "GET"
> method [RFC2616] for the authorization endpoint and MAY support the
> use of the "POST" method as well.

So before I implement anything custom to trigger a POST request to the authorization server I am integrating with, I was just curious if anyone knew of a way to get Spring Security to trigger a POST for the /authorization instead of a /GET.

Curious if I'm missing where that functionality is supported, if at all.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use springsecurity and oauth2server to configure your login model and through this interface to login
POST:
http://your_ip:port/auth/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=username&password=password&client_id=yourclientid&client_secret=yoursecret

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I'm asking for the step BEFORE the /token endpoint request. The /authorize endpoint (fetching the authorization code). Spring Security appears to exclusively call this endpoint with a /GET request, I'm curious if its possible by means of a POST, any ideas?